# changed file not showing up in my terminal

Tags: git, command-line

How come I can only stage for commits if I'm in my root directory? I don't know what I did but now I can only stage for commits in my root directory. Before I was able to stage files for commit anywhere in the directory that it's in.

Comment: Does the file show up anywhere when you run `git status`?  Do you have a `.gitignore` rule which could be applicable to this file?

Comment: the file does not show up anywhere when I run `git status`. I do have a `.gitignore` file but that file is not in it. When I re-opened my terminal and changed the bash prompt(for fun), I can see that the file now appears when I run `git status`. Still curious as to why it didn't appear before.